# Filter fields with multiple delimiters

Tags: awk

I've done extensive searching for a solution but can't quite find what I need.  Have a file like this:

```
aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd~eee^fff^ggg|hhh|iii

111|222|333|444~555^666^777|888|999

AAA|BBB|CCC||EEE|FFF
```

What I want to do is use awk or something else to return lines from this file with a change to field 4(pipe delimited).  Field 4 has a tilde and caret as delimiters which is where I'm struggling.  We want the lines returned as this:

```
aaa|bbb|ccc|eee|hhh|iii

111|222|333|555|888|999

AAA|BBB|CCC||EEE|FFF
```

If field 4 is empty, it's returned as is.  But when field 4 has multiple values, we want the first value right after the tilde returned only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' '{sub(/^[^~]*~/, "", $4); sub(/\^.*/, "", $4)} 1' OFS='|' file
aaa|bbb|ccc|eee|hhh|iii
111|222|333|555|888|999
AAA|BBB|CCC||EEE|FFF
```

This approach makes no assumption about the contents of fields other than field 4.  The other fields may, for example, contain `~` or `^` characters and that will not affect the results.

#### How it works

- `-F'|'`

  This sets the field delimiter on input to `|`.
- `sub(/^[^~]*~/, "", $4)`

  If field 4 contains a `~`, this removes the first `~` and everything before the first `~`.
- `sub(/\^.*/, "", $4)`

  If field 4 contains `^`, this removes the first `^` and everything after it.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.
- `OFS='|'`

  This sets the field separator on output to `|`.

Comment: Thank you both!  I am impressed!  Appreciate the quick response.  Both of these appear to do what I want.  Thanks for the explanation as well to further my understanding.

Comment: @tw84 You're welcome.  Be aware that if any field other field 4 contains `~` or `^`, the two approaches may give different answers.

Comment: Good point, John.  There actually could be other fields with ^ or ~ in them but I was trying to simplify.  Looks like your solution still works in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F "[|^~]" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}NF==6{print} NF==9{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$9}' tmp.txt 

aaa|bbb|ccc|eee|hhh|iii
111|222|333|555|888|999
AAA|BBB|CCC||EEE|FFF
```

use a regular expression as your delimiter
count the fields to decide what to do
set the output delimiter to pipe